# Ros enabled plugin examples use c++11?

Tags: ros, gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am following:
http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=guided_i&tut=guided_i6

I keep getting " ‘thread’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type " make errors that refer to the code in the guide:
private: std::thread rosQueueThread;

in my CMakeLists I have
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${GAZEBO_CXX_FLAGS}")

I am using gazebo 1.9.6 and ROS hydro

It seems like these examples are using c++11?
Are there some ROS enabled plugin examples that do not use c++11?
I am clearly missing something here :) Thanks for all the help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13869/ros-enabled-plugin-examples-use-c++11-?/) by [JuliusS](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2696/juliuss/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2016-07-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Gazebo only supports C++11 from version 5.

[This](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_gzplugins&cat=connect_ros) tutorial might be relevant to you, it's listed as working for Gazebo versions 1.9+.

#### Regarding tutorials organization

The tutorials live in [this](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_tutorials) repository. Anyone can add or edit tutorials from there. Bigger changes to the website organization can't be done directly, but feel free to open an issue with your proposals.

In any case, I actually found this one by googling for "gazebo ros plugin", it was the first link from http://gazebosim.org that came up.

Another hint for finding tutorials is to use the [browse](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/browse) view and do a `Ctrl+F` on the page.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JuliusS](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2696/juliuss/) on 2016-07-14**:
Oh I see. This is exactly what I needed. Is there a way to propose enhancements for gazebosim.org  tutorials organisation? I would have never found that myself haha Seems like older versions of gazebo  are lost in the sands of time

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2016-07-14**:
I updated the answer with some comments about searching for tutorials ;)

**Comment by [JuliusS](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2696/juliuss/) on 2016-07-14**:
Thanks, this is great. I think its just easy start of on a wrong path sometimes :p I did the whole velodyne plugin tutorial until it started not compiling haha

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2016-07-14**:
I opened an issue about this: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_tutorials/issues/65/add-a-noticeable-requirements-section-for